# An example of discontinuous function on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is there any example of a function which is discontinuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Surely you are joking...

Comment: Do you mean [nowhere continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function)?

Comment: Yes I mean nowhere continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean a function that is nowhere continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, you may consider the indicator function of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a good example. I am looking for more answers.

Comment: I didn't know it had a name, but yes it seems to be the Dirichlet function.